# Webscarab and the latest Mozilla version 121

Tags: version, mozilla, webscarab

I tried to configure Webscarab in Mozilla Firefox Settings (latest Version 121) .However , it did not work . As I could not connect to the internet after configuring  Mozilla version 121 . Does Webscarab even  work with Mozilla latest version 121 ? There is no answer to this question in Google and in Stackoverflow . That is why I asked the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why?? WebScarab has not been updated for many, many years.
Use a tool that is updated, like [ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/) :)